# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.dispatch' has no attribute 'add_fallback_dispatch_list'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Why the following error only when running Jupyter notebook via Anaconda Navigator?

 I've tried `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` but it doesn't help and the error remains.

 However, it is fine without this error when running on Colaboratory.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Bidirectional, LSTM, Dropout, Dense 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
```

Error snapshot
[image]

Comment: Found any fix? I am getting the same error. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling possibly every version. But nothing seems to help. Has been two days now

Comment: No @DIVYARATHOD. I am now doing it in Colab since it runs fine there. Do share with us on how you resolved it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Reason might be a wrong version of tensorflow-estimator being installed.

Can you try:

```
!pip uninstall tensorflow-estimator

!pip install tensorflow-estimator==2.1
```

in Jupyter notebook.

If this didn't work:

```
conda remove tensorflow
conda install tensorflow-estimator=2.1
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1
```

reinstall tensorflow and try importing?

Comment: Hey! I have tried this and also possibly every other version. My current tensorflow version is 2.7 and tensorflow-estimator version is 2.7 as well. But it's not working for me. I'm really stuck

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new environment and then run.
Else, if you are running it in a new environment then, try the base environment.
This resolves issue some times.